# USB ports seems to be broke in ubuntu 20.04 with a lenovo t540P with kernel update for listening music output

Tags: sound, usb, music

Recently I have been experience that all my music from my hard disk is impossible to listen to it properly cause the sounds stops in the middle of the songs.

1. I open a music player (lollypop, audacious, emby, jellyfin)
2. I play shuffle music from my hard disk, through my dj set using usb ports
3. The music starts playing and after some seconds the song keeps playing but not sound anymore through the speakers
4. It happens in all the music players with different songs

Log that I get:

```
17:49:49 kernel: usb 2-3: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
17:49:38 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
17:49:38 kernel: usb 2-3: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
17:49:33 kernel: psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
17:49:33 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
17:49:33 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
17:49:32 kernel: usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 3
17:49:32 kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
17:49:32 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
17:49:32 kernel: rmi4_f01 rmi4-00.fn01: found RMI device, manufacturer: Synaptics, product: tm2964-001, fw id: 1637231
17:49:32 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
17:49:32 kernel: rmi4_smbus 0-002c: registering SMbus-connected sensor
17:49:32 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
17:49:32 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
17:49:32 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
17:49:32 kernel: at24 0-0050: 256 byte spd EEPROM, read-only
17:49:32 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
17:49:31 kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
17:49:31 kernel: hid-generic 0003:08E4:0156.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [PIONEER Corporation. PIONEER CDJ-350] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input4
17:49:31 kernel: usb 2-12: Manufacturer: SunplusIT INC.
17:49:31 kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: Trying to set up SMBus access
17:49:31 kernel: usb 2-11: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
17:49:31 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
17:49:31 kernel: usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
17:49:31 kernel: usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 2014102101094B
17:49:31 kernel: sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
17:49:31 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
17:49:31 kernel: scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8E2    SB01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
17:49:31 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
17:49:31 kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG MZ7TE128 6L0Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
17:49:31 kernel: usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
17:49:31 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
17:49:31 kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
17:49:31 kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
17:49:31 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
17:49:31 kernel: scsi host5: ahci
17:49:31 kernel: hub 3-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
17:49:31 kernel: usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
17:49:31 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
17:49:31 kernel: i2c i2c-0: Successfully instantiated SPD at 0x50
17:49:31 kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq ilck pm led clo pio slum part ems apst 
17:49:31 kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
17:49:31 kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: 15 ports detected
17:49:31 kernel: usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
17:49:31 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000000009810
17:49:31 kernel: acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
17:49:31 kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
17:49:31 kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Detected 0 cards
17:49:31 kernel: rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one month, y3k, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
17:49:31 kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
17:49:31 kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
17:49:31 kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
17:49:31 kernel: tpm_tis 00:05: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0x0, rev-id 78)
17:49:31 kernel: thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
17:49:31 kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
17:49:31 kernel: pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xf0400000-0xf0bfffff 64bit pref]
17:49:31 kernel: pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf0400000-0xf0bfffff 64bit pref]
17:49:31 kernel: pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SMO1200 PNP0c31 (active)
17:49:31 kernel: system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
17:49:31 kernel: pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
17:49:31 kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4bfff window]
17:49:31 kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform retains control of PCIe features (AE_SUPPORT)
```

I have just downgrade the kernel from 5.13 to 5.10 and the usb works now perfectly. So it is a kernel problem.

```
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0480:a207 Toshiba America Inc External USB 3.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 08e4:0156 Pioneer Corp. PIONEER CDJ-350
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd  Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Hello. If the music is played through the mini jack connection, is not a problem. The same if it is played in the speaker build in . The streaming music has the same problem while is played through the usb ports.
I have just downgrade the kernel from 5.13 to 5.0 and it works perfectly. So there is update in the kernel that has create this problem.
I am using a Lenovo T540P computer

Comment: You had `lsusb` output in a comment for a moment -- that's what you need to [edit] into the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant understand. Do I have to write the lsusb output in the question?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: Can I confirm the working kernel is 5. **0**? That's much lower than 20.04 has been tested to run with ... 

Comment: Is there something else that can be done to fix the issue?